# Is it possible to create services and DTO from existing entity?

Tags: jhipster

I am seeking for a way to create DTO and service automatically from entity. To be more specific I've created some entities and their relationship using JDL-studio and imported using jhipster cli but I didn't found dto and service. Even I tried other option like changing .json file under .jhipster folder but no luck.

Is there any option out there?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I found the solution myself that once the entity is created the entity json file will also automatically created on **.jhipster** folder and for the service and DTO what we have to do is we've to just put following properties on .json entity.

```
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "service": "serviceImpl",
    "microserviceName": "WntVehicleAuthority",
```

and after that we 've to issue **yo jhipster:entity EntityName** and it will automatically generate service and dto.
Note only mention Entity name not extension
ie, **yo jhipster:entity Employee**

Comment: thanks i was using "dto": yes, which obiously didn't worked.